# multidimensional very large array

Tags: arraylist, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, malloc, dynamic-arrays

Hi i want to use multidimensional very large array. I tried following code. It compiles but when i execute it it gives me segmentation fault error.

```
'int NT = 35; int NX = 25; int NY = 25; int NZ = 25;
double dt = 0.1; double dx = 0.5; double dy = 0.5; double dz = 0.5;

double PosT[NT]; 
double PosX[NX]; double PosY[NY]; double PosZ[NZ];

for(int i=0;i<NT;i++)
    PosT[i] = i*dt+dt;
for(int i=0; i<NX;i++)
    PosX[i] = dx*i;
for(int i=0; i<NY;i++)
    PosY[i] = dy*i;
for(int i=0; i<NZ;i++)
    PosZ[i] = dz*i;

double* b_x=(double*)malloc(NX*NY*NZ*sizeof(double));
double* b_y=(double*)malloc(NX*NY*NZ*sizeof(double));
double** B=(double**)malloc(NX*NY*NZ*NT*sizeof(double*));

if(b_x==NULL||b_y==NULL){
    cout<<"Malloc space error!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
    for(int ix=0;ix<NX;ix++){
        for(int iy=0;iy<NY;iy++){
            for(int iz=0;iz<NZ;iz++){
                int position=ix*NY*NZ+iy*NZ+iz; 
                b_x[position] =0.;
                b_y[position] =0.;
            }
        }
    }'
```

but when i work in below part then i got segmentation error, my codes next part is following lines which include 2d arrays. and this 2d array is very large , 
perhaps due to this i am getting segmentation error

```
    'if(B==NULL){
    cout<<"Malloc space error!"<<endl;
    return 0;
    }
    cout<<"work"<<endl;
        for(int ix=0;ix<NX;ix++){
        for(int iy=0;iy<NY;iy++){
            for(int iz=0;iz<NZ;iz++){
                int position=ix*NY*NZ+iy*NZ+iz;
                for(int it=0;it<NT;it++){               
                B[position][it]=0.;
            }
        }
    }
}
 cout<<"not working"<<endl;'
```

so code between work and not working has problem which causes segmentation error. Any solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

> `int NT = 35; int NX = 25; int NY = 25; int NZ = 25;`

For simplicity, let's change all of these to `NT=NX=NY=NZ=2`. This line:

```
double** B=(double**)malloc(NX*NY*NZ*NT*sizeof(double*));
```

would then allocate space for 16 pointers. On the first iteration through the loops, this line:

```
B[position][it]=0.;
```

would be equivalent to:

```
double *tmp = B[0];  // Load uninitialized pointer from B[0]
tmp[0] = 0.0;        // Dereference uninitialized pointer to store something.
```

It shouldn't be at all surprising that this code results in a SIGSEGV.

What you *probably* meant:

```
double *B = malloc(NX*NY*NZ*NT*sizeof(double));
for(int ix = 0; ix < NX; ix++) {
  for(int iy = 0; iy < NY; iy++) {
    for(int iz = 0; iz < NZ; iz++) {
       for(int it = 0; it < NT; it++) {
         int position = NT * (NZ * (NY * ix + iy) + iz) + it;
         B[position] = 0.0;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: but then my position in b_x[position] , b_y[position] and B[position][it] are not same. i want position to be same in b_x, b_y and B , but B further decays with time so [position][it]